# How to handle Data being saved twice when clicked once in My Sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have made a **users** database which creates a record age, name, email, & password. I used  **sequelize ORM** for My Sql database.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("users", {
        age: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        tokens: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });
    return User;
};
```

After taking input for the record, i have used **bcrypt** for hashing and storing the password safely.

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.age) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Age can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    if (!req.body.name) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Name can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    if (!req.body.email) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "email can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    if (!req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Password can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    const tutorials = {
        age: req.body.age,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    Users.create(tutorials)
        .then(data => {
            try {
                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8);
                Users.build({ age: req.body.age, name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: hash })
                    .save()
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Created Database with Hashed password'
                })
                return;
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                res.status(500).send('something broke')
            }
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the User."
            });
        });
};
```

Now when i hit the API, i get 2 list in my users table

```
id  age  name     email              password       
1   1   Trial1  Trial1@gmail.com    Trial1@123  
2   1   Trial1  Trial1@gmail.com $2a$08$v0Bax1fXFTC5VKnkrlPpxu5vDenWRKgMLvr0POyWimiwqNCZKYwr2
```

But i want only one record to be stored with hashed password and not plain text password. Please help me fix it.

Comment: You can add debounce on the method. So, It will be only called once in a specific time.

Comment: `@apoorvachikara` can you please write and send it!

Comment: Because i don't know how to use debounce, so i don't know where to use it in my code.

Comment: What you are doing is saving two records to the DB one with hashed password and other one is without hash. A simple fix would be only save hashed one.  Check from the code you must be calling create multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In `sequelize`, the following two ways of inserting data are equivalent:

```
let mickey = await User.create({
        username: 'mickey_mouse',
        e-mail: 'mickey@example.com'
    })

// is equivalent to

let mickey = User.build({
        username: 'mickey_mouse',
        e-mail: 'mickey@example.com'
    })
await mickey.save()
```

Also, it might be best not to save the password in the database and then subsequently update it with the hash.  Instead, the hash can be saved with the initial insert, like this:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.age) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Age can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    if (!req.body.name) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Name can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    if (!req.body.email) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "email can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    if (!req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Password can not be empty!"
        })
    }
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8);
    const tutorials = {
        age: req.body.age,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash
    };
    Users.create(tutorials)
        .then(user => {
            try {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Created Database with Hashed password'
                })
                return;
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                res.status(500).send('something broke')
            }
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the User."
            });
        });
};
```